# creating an email address book

Tags: android, arrays, email

I am wanting my user to send a simple text string to one or more emails from an address book of varying size (as addresses are created and deleted), which will appear in the xml.preferences resources. The list of emails I'm guessing should be stored in an array and be called by:

How do I do this such that the user can add an email to the address book. The entries are simple and are easily done by:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="enterEmail"/>
```

But in the `enterEmail` method how are new entries permanently and persistently stored for later use?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need for this is described in the official [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

It describes all necessary steps to create a database and interact (insert, read, update or delete data) with it.

In your case a database with a single table `email_addresses` with two columns `_id` (used to easily identify an inserted email address) and `email_address` (for the email address itself) should be sufficient. Your `enterEmail` method should perform an insert operation.

You may also want to add the possibility to delete an already inserted email address.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you